# Holes in brick mortar?

Tags: brick, mortar

There are a couple holes in my house's exterior brick mortar about 3/8" in diameter.  Is there any reason not to fill them in?  I only hesitate because my masonry knowledge is pretty much nil.  Both are beneath windows (one is far below, though), but I wonder if they could just be old anchor holes since one is below three anchors.

First hole:

[image: Hole1]

Zoomed in:

[image: Hole1 zoomed]

Second hole (mind the photo bomb):

[image: Hole2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holes near the bottom of the wall are "weep" holes that let any water that gets behind the bricks drain out.  These, however, are not weep holes and look like they were drilled to mount something to the wall.  Perhaps a hose rack or reel?

In any case, yes you can fill them in.  They are small enough that you could use some mortal-colored caulk.

By the way, you should probably address that crack also.

Comment: Ah, yeah I was pretty sure they weren't weep holes since they're so high up and inconsistent.  Today's task is filling in those cracks with acrylic mortar sealant, so I'll fill in those holes, too.